# Issue with date slicer and COALESCE function

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a matrix table witch is filtered with a Date lookup table, which works fine:

Currenly filtered from June to November.

I then created the following function:

```
satisfactionRate = 

VAR SatRate =
CALCULATE(
    [Total answers],
    Satisfaction[Satisfied]="Yes"
)/
[Total answers]

RETURN
COALESCE(SatRate ,1)
```

For some reason after adding this value to the matrix, it now includes all dates from january through november, instead of keeping the filter (from june through november).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a typo in your measure. Shouldn't it be `COALESCE(SatRate, 1)` ?
Also use `DIVIDE` over `/` as it provides an alternative result for when the denominator is 0.

If that doesn't solve it, then please update your question with a snip of your data model so we can see any Date table with relationships, what `Total answers` dax expression is, and which fields you are using for your visual.